# How to fix error with ATI driver "Error of failed request"?

Tags: 11.10, ati, fglrx

I installed the fglrx catalyst proprietary driver via this link : http://cisight.com/install-amd-radeon-hd-6470m-and-solve-overheat-on-ubuntu-1110-oneiric/

Running `fglrxinfo` or `glxinfo | grep render` returns :

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
Serial number of failed request:  12
Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

my xorg is :

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "fglrx"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

How may I solve it?

Comment: could you open a terminal and copy and paste `glxinfo | grep render` and post the output here ?

Comment: 1@1-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ glxinfo | grep render
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12

Comment: @user34785 Please click edit on your question and add the information there, thanks!

Comment: In my very similar problem (xorg.conf is a bit different) I get [these maybe problematic lines](http://paste.ubuntu.com/777169/) in Xorg.0.log :

Comment: Moving on in my problem : `lsmod | grep fglrx` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial: http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/12/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-1112-linux.html

Comment: Nope I haven't specifically followed those but  [wiki.cchtml.com](http://wiki.cchtml.com) gives similar instructions with more details

Answer (score 6):

Check if fglrx isn't blacklisted.

To do that you can grep through all of the files in /etc/modprobe.d/:

```
grep fglrx /etc/modprobe.d/*
```

In my case this gives following output:

```
blacklist-local.conf:blacklist fglrx
fglrx.conf:# This file was installed by fglrx
fglrx.conf:alias fglrx fglrx
```

All I had to do is to edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-local.conf file and comment out line with "blacklist fglrx" by inserting "#" in front of the line. So it looks like this now:

```
# blacklist fglrx
```

I hope you could understand what i am writting here and it will help you solve your problem.

Comment: Hmm nice idea but it isn't blacklisted

Comment: I'll be awarding you the bounty, because I find you gave the most helpful answer. (Even though it did not help me)

Comment: This solved every problem with catalyst 12.4 driver for me. Why it was blacklisted in the first place beats me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

there is a nice script smxi for ATI / Nvidia try this:

```
   sudo su
   mkdir video
   cd video
   wget -Nc smxi.org/sgfxi
   chmod +x sgfxi
   ./sgfxi
```

the script automatically stops X server, detects the video card type, downloads the last video driver from vendor's site, backups xorg.conf and installs the driver

Comment: This solution worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

Use propriety drivers through the "Additional Drivers" application. Going for a manual install of upstream drivers is unnecessary. Open terminal and enter:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

and restart your computer. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial is simply full of wrong steps and commands and do not describe correctly every passage.

Watch this if you want a good resource for docs http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Following the instructions did not solve the problem (at least for me)

Answer (score 1):

Hey I got the same problem:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
Serial number of failed request:  12
Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

When I did:

```
fglrxinfo
```

It gave me the same output:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
Serial number of failed request:  12
Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

So I followed the instructions in this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong during your installation.
Remove fglrx first:

```
 sudo /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
 sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri fglrx-modaliases
```

Now you can try installing fglrx again. Run jockey-gtk and install the proposed driver.

Answer (score 0):

If all other comments did not work, try this one.. (for ATI users) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Answer (score 0):

Having tried several tricks that did not work, I ventured the sgfxi mentioned above. Unfortunately, it stopped when it was about to install the proprietary driver telling me to uninstall another driver installation. But, it did not look like any driver was installed, so I could not uninstall ... and X was broken.

However, it was not too bad, because I had already downloaded the propritary drivers (14.10) from amd and created the three deb packages, and ran:

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Then X worked again, and the request bug had disappeared.

See section 3.1. here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

AMD-driver:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx

It looks like sgfxi had removed enough of the old installation to make the re-installed driver work without the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of lspci to confirm that your AMD/ATI video card is listed. Seriously!

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

After wasting hours removing and reinstalling my video drivers with no difference it turned out my that PCIe card needed to be removed and reinstalled! /facepalm