# Compiz/unity not working

Tags: unity, compiz, ati

sorry for my bad english but i'm french.

Well, i have this new ubuntu with unity and compiz just doesn't work.

As you can see i have everything i need checked :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aykyc.png

and :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIEnV.png

But after this when i close, minimize or anything, nothing happends.
I don't know what to do, i already have the driver for my graphic card.

Thanks ;)

Comment: You could try this command in a terminal: `compiz --replace &` and see if there are any errors in the output. Then `disown %1` so it doesn't die when you exit the terminal.

Comment: hello and thanks for your time.

I'm getting few errors :

Comment: @Githlar
http://i.imgur.com/l1bwe.png

Comment: It seems that compiz is not using my ATI card but my intel HD graphic.

Comment: I'm having the same problem I'm not sure how it's effecting your PC but my whole entire launch bar and menu bar is missing and when I use the command 'ccsm' and try to enable unity and disable anythings that my conflict it says it's enabled for a second but then it wants me to enable Expo, OpenGL, and Scale. but it always ends with them all automatically unenabling all the enabled plugins

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before (unfortunately mine caused a kernel panic at boot)! If you're not using something like Bumblebee to save power (i.e. you're on a desktop) you can blacklist your Intel on-board video by adding this line to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist

`blacklist intel-agp`

Then reboot

Comment: Humm It still doesn't work. I didn't have the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist so i created it. But i had this one /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. I added the line at both files on by one and both at the ame time but it still doesn't work ...

Comment: Btw i tried this /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p. But i had bad request. So i've come here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/81344/how-to-fix-error-with-ati-driver-error-of-failed-request

Comment: and in /etc/modpobe.d/fglrx.conf i can read : blacklist radeon

Comment: should i comment this line ?

Comment: I'm sorry. Before I *did* mean blacklist.conf. Actually, did you install the drivers with "Additional Drivers"? Or the official ones? If it's got a green light in "Additional Drivers," it means it's installed. Honestly, I had nothing but heartache with ATI cards in Ubuntu after the first two I gave up on them and used nVidia (they're much better supported). Then again, that was in 2007. But, I realized that some people don't have an option (i.e. Built-in on a laptop)