# Fglrx causes serious bug-black screen!

Tags: ati, fglrx, hybrid-graphics

I downloaded newest driver from Ati site and installed it...

Now at start-up I see a black screen and message:

> "Your screen,graphics card,and input device settings could not be
>   detected correctly.You will need to configure these yourself."

I press enter and move to next screen with message:

> "What would you like to do?"

and listed below:

> "Run in low graphics mode for just one session."

(it is marked) and some other options that could not possibly to mark with TAB or up,down,left,right or shift key... (no cursor). I can not login to system and can not use it!    **What should I do?**

Comment: Please for any help.How to access the terminal?How to disable fglrx from there?Is it possible that even the latest Ubuntu does not support switchable graphics,although many newer laptops usig switchable graphics,although this problem makes Ubuntu unusable for a large number of laptops???

Answer (score 5):

**(1) Check if fglrx is blacklisted.** (This was my solution on my HP pavilion dv7 with a AMD/Ati Radeon HD 6770M)

To do that you can grep through all of the files in `/etc/modprobe.d/`:

```
grep fglrx /etc/modprobe.d/*
```

In my case this gives following output:

```
blacklist-local.conf:blacklist fglrx
fglrx.conf:# This file was installed by fglrx
fglrx.conf:alias fglrx fglrx
```

All I had to do is to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-local.conf` file and comment out line with `blacklist fglrx` by inserting `#` in front of the line. So it looks like this now:

`# blacklist fglrx`
credits: Gumili([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81344/how-to-fix-error-with-ati-driver-error-of-failed-request))

**(2) Reinstall fglrx**

```
apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-updates
```

**(3) Re-run fglrx initiate**

```
 amdconfig --initial -f
```

Here is the documentation this command

```
AMD Initial Configuration:
  --initial
        Generate a default AMD device section in the configuration file which
        is capable of loading the fglrx driver.
 --initial=dual-head
        Same as '--initial' but generate a basic dual head configuration file.
  --initial=check
        Identifies if the fglrx driver is present in configuration file.
```

**(4) Reboot**

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in Ubuntu 12.04 I had AMD Catalyst Display Driver 12.6 on my HP Pavilion g7-1075dx (ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250) running great for about one week with my 24" second monitor (as Generic Non-PnP monitor in Windows) 1920x1080 via HDMI cable (through SVGA cable I couldn't get a high resolution). I downloaded the driver from http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx.

I must have not disconnected the 2nd monitor gracefully before shutting down, because when I booted up this morning I got this black screen.

I spent 3 hours getting my laptop to successfully boot up again.

The key is to be able to make changes to the hard drive: Boot up then hold down the Shift key to get the GRUB bootloader menu. Arrow down to to the first Ubuntu version with **(recovery mode)**.

You will get the **Recovery Menu (filesystem state: read-only)**. You want to change it to write to the file system: arrow down to **dpkg   Repair broken packages** and press enter. Do **Yes** to remount filesystem in read/write mode.

Next, `apt-get upgrade` will run automatically in the terminal session; let it go and at the end press <kbd>N</kbd> to not continue and to not start the upgrade.

Then `apt-get upgrade` will churn some more then say `Finished, please press ENTER`; press <kbd>Enter</kbd> which will then take you back to the Recovery Menu but now you are in filesystem read/write state.

Next, arrow down to **root  Drop to root shell prompt**, give the password, and voila you have a root prompt on a read/write file system.

I tried Apple16's excellent suggestions:
(1) I commented out the line in `blacklist-local.conf` and then once again including commenting out a line in `blacklist-fglrx.conf` and rebooted but it didn't work.
Also, (2) and (3) did not work for me but they might for you.

Finally, I decided to revert to square zero: Back up `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and copy `xorg.conf.failsafe` over it. Then reboot and at least now the PC is usable. Next for me it's back to reinstalling the graphics drivers again.

Comment: You should be able to run `mount -o remount,rw /` from the root shell rather than going through the `dpkg` rigmarole. Apparently the **enable networking** option also automatically remounts the filesystem read-write

Answer (score 0):

On a Dell Precision M4800 recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12 to Ubuntu 14, installing module-assistant and fglrx made it work for me.

<kbd>Crtl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a shell, then

```
sudo apt-get install module-assistant
sudo apt-get install fglrx
sudo shutdown -r now  # To restart your computer
```

fixed the graphic card error messages.

I am still having trouble after authentication in the gnome login screen.  However, I believe this is a problem with the encrypted home directory, as other users with no encrypted directory work fine.

Answer (score 0):

My screen was blacking after booting Ubuntu after installing AMD drivers on my Ubuntu 20.04. Then I uninstalled AMD drivers and everything went fine.

I did:

1. Follow the steps in [iggye2014's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/178706/527764) up to **root Drop to root shell prompt'**.
2. On the root prompt type `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`.(If it doesn't work try without pro: `amdgpu-uninstall`) And then `apt autoremove`.

Comment: @Zanna Thanks! But in my case `sudo apt autoremove` worked.