# Edubuntu boots in  low graphics mode. with an Intel HD Graphics system

Tags: intel-graphics, hd-video, edubuntu

I have a HD Intel graphics card in my laptop.  It was working fine the first few days with the new version Edubuntu.

Now when you start, just before it goes to the part asking for the login password
*I think the OP means lightdm*  it sends me to a low graphics mode.

Things I've tried:

- I tried <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
- Updated and installed fglrx from the terminal.

All my work is all stored there. Please, if anyone knows how to fix this, tell me.

Original version:

hola tengo una tarjeta intel hd graphics en mi laptop estuve trabajando los primeros dias bien con la nueva version edubuntu solo que ahora cuando inicia y justo antes de que pase a la parte que me pide la contraseña me manda low graphic  mode  no se que hacer ya entre y le di ctr alt f1 y actualice  tmb instale fglrx necesito obtener toda miinformacion todo mi trabajo esta ahi guardado, por favor si alguien sabe como solucionar este bug digame como, gracias, ciao.

Answer (score 0):

see my answer here:

[Fglrx causes serious bug-black screen!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133844/fglrx-causes-serious-bug-black-screen/142515#142515)

Comment: http://www.edubuntu.org/about

Comment: Ah, I did not know about that, thanks. My answer still is relevant though, and could solve his problem.