# Blank screen during boot with open radeon drivers

Tags: boot, ati, kubuntu, radeon

Right after the grub boot screen I get a blank screen and my monitor goes to standby with "No signal". But after some time the graphical login screen `sddm` will appear and I can log in and use KDE just fine. I'm currently running the latest Kubuntu 15.04 Beta 2.

I've tried both drivers, fglrx and the open radeon driver. With the fglrx driver I see the boot screen, but not with the radeon drivers.

I'd prefer to use the radeon drivers because I'm having graphical glitches with the fglrx drivers. Another problem with the fglrx driver I have is that I get a blank screen when switching to a virtual terminal.

Here are some infos:

Xorg.0.log: http://pastebin.com/NM7zaPqm

```
simon@simon-kubuntu:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cypress PRO [Radeon HD 5850] [1002:6899]
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:0348]                                                                                                                                                                         
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

How do I get my screen back during boot?

Comment: check this if it hepls http://askubuntu.com/questions/133844/fglrx-causes-serious-bug-black-screen try to blacklist fglrx

Comment: Thanks, but that link discusses problems with the fglrx driver and how to fix them. I've uninstalled the fglrx driver and am using the radone driver now, that's where I have the problem with black screen during boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Put the line `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=auto` just below the line `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` in the file `/etc/default/grub`. I had the same problem and this fix completely solved it.

([Source](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1570))

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! This worked! It didn't bring back the Kubuntu logo during boot, but I don't care, now I can at least see some output of kernel messages. Much better than a black screen and wondering why the boot is taking so long :)