# X Error of failed request: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)

Tags: 12.04, xorg, fglrx, opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix error with ATI driver “Error of failed request”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81344/how-to-fix-error-with-ati-driver-error-of-failed-request)

Though this question is asked [before for 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81344/how-to-fix-error-with-ati-driver-error-of-failed-request), it's still unanswered. I am using ubuntu 12.04 (on Dell Inspiron 1525, 2008 model) and facing the same problem:

```
milind@Ubuntu11:~$ glxinfo
name of display: :0.0
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

From internet, I tried several tricks, say removing/reinstalling some packages like Xorg or flglrx (ATI); but no luck.

The "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" file gives:

> (EE) GLX error: Can not get required symbols.

I have another newer laptop (lenovo thinkpad T420 2011 model) which also has Ubuntu 12.04, but there everything is working fine. But don't know what to compare between working and not working laptops!

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I kept trying and used the combination of
[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/131027/22704)
[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/126513/22704)
[this link](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/15652)

And it worked like a charm:

```
milind@Ubuntu11:~$ glxinfo | grep -i yes
direct rendering: Yes
```

At least as of now, I am able to run some basic OpenGL programs ([source code link mentioned here](http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/get_opengl_setup_linux/video.php)).

Comment: The first link (http://askubuntu.com/a/218894/73423) was all it took to fix my problem (Ubuntu 12.04 on Acer TravelMate 5520, ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT). Thanks.

Comment: why do I get this error? $ glxinfo | grep -i yes
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42