# Ati driver installation problem on Mobilyty HD Radeon 4250

Tags: radeon

I have laptop Compaq Presario CQ-56 with Mobility Radeon 4250 . I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , I used this guide ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI ) from step 3.1 to step with fglrxinfo , and i saw in my terminal info about chipset GPU only  . I repaired broken packages from Synaptic , but after rebooting the system i tried this command in terminal "gksudo amdcccle" and now i see one window where sad i don't have any installed driver in my machine ... and if i use `fglrxinfo` i see this

```
mtrx@Anaconda:~$ fglrxinfo
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

If i start from System settings Additional Drivers i see "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system"
Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Now i use Kubuntu 12.04 LTS and i dont have problems with ati drivers , I installed them by going to **Additional drivers** in `software-properties-gtk` without problems !

```
mtrx@Anaconda:~$ fglrxinfo 
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11627 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall fglrx-driver
```

Then reboot your PC , after doing the reboot execute this command

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

hope that helps.

Comment: nope , same result

[code]mtrx@Anaconda:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall fglrx-driver
[sudo] password for mtrx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package fglrx-driver is a virtual package provided by:
  fglrx 2:8.970-0ubuntu1
  fglrx-updates 2:9.000-0ubuntu0.3
  fglrx-experimental-9 2:9.010-0ubuntu0.3
  fglrx-experimental-12 2:12.100-0ubuntu0.1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'fglrx-driver' has no installation candidate[/code] afther restart just found fglrx prim. dev. section and create xorg backup

Comment: i have found this . can it help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/81344/how-to-fix-error-with-ati-driver-error-of-failed-request

Comment: nope didnt help , only with script smxi i saw progress , gpu is not supported for this driver or something else ... that i saw in window .